# TS. Typify js_function_decoration and generic narrowing (or "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter")

Tags: typescript, decorator, type-narrowing

I want (in function `run`) to get one of the known functions and pass corresponding arguments.

```
type Name = 'f1' | 'f2' | 'f3';
const fns = {
  f1: () => {},
  f2: (a: string) => {},
  f3: (a: string, b: string) => {}
};
const argsArr = {
  f1: [],
  f2: ['str'],
  f3: [1, 2]
};

function run(name: Name) {
  const fn = fns[name];
  const args = argsArr[name];
  fn(...args);   // "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter"
}
```

But at `fn(...args)` that causes the ts-error "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter". Because, as I think, TS doesnt think there is a guarantee that the `args` type is corresponding to the function. So, I'm looking for a way to narrow the type of `name` parameter, so to narrow/infer the type of `fn` (to make TS understand that although they may vary, they always correspond to each other).

---

Btw, I tried variants of the following, doesn't work:

```
function run<N extends Name, F extends Fn>(name: N) {
  const fn= fns[name] as F;
  type Args = Parameters<typeof fn>;
  const args:Args = argsArr[name] as Args;
  fn(...args);
}
```

Btw2, I didn't find typifying of comon decorators of functions (not TS Decorators) it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add type for 'fns' object.

```
type Fns = {
  [key in Name]: (...args: any) => void
}

const fns: Fns = {
  f1: () => {},
  f2: (a: string) => {},
  f3: (a: string, b: string) => {},
};
```

Then error is gone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is — typescript doesn't have any constraints defined for `fns` and `argsArr`, so it infers the types of these variables to the best of its ability, which is not enough in this case.

I managed to get it working with this code:

```
type Name = 'f1' | 'f2' | 'f3';

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => void;
const fns = {
    f1: () => { },
    f2: (a: string) => { },
    f3: (a: string, b: string) => { }
} satisfies Record<Name, Fn>

const argsArr: {
    [Key in Name]: Parameters<typeof fns[Key]>
} = {
    f1: [],
    f2: ['str'],
    f3: [1, 2]
} 

function run(name: Name) {
    const fn: Fn = fns[name];
    const args = argsArr[name];
    fn(...args);   // "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter"
}
```

**What changed:**

- Function type is extracted to type `Fn`.
- `fns` now has the lower constrain `Record<Name, Fn>` using `satisfies`, which allows to properly infer the functions args to use later and constrains the key to only be `Name`.
- `argsArr` keys constrained to `Name` with the values being constrained to the args of the corresponding functions. This results in a type error for `f3` (as expected), since it has `number` values instead of `string` ones.
- in function `run`, `fn` variable is typed as `Fn` because it needs to lose the exact types in favor for more general ones to not give any type errors when calling it. `args` type remains the same, since now it fits the more general function constraint.